# How to group_by more elegantly my data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

I have two tables:

- One where I know for sure **all** users of this table **df1** have used a feature called "*Folder*"
- The other where I **don't know** if users of this table **df2** have used a feature called "*Folder*"

I want to build a graph showing the number of users that used the Folder feature on each date.
So the main data frame I want to build is a data frame with **ALL** the Dates included (from df1 and df2) and for each date the number of users who used this feature "Folder".

Here is a reproducible example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Date=c("2021-05-12","2021-05-15","2021-05-20"),user_ID=c("RZ625","TDH65","EJ7336"))
colnames(df1) <- c("Date", "user_ID")

df2 <- data.frame(Date=c("2021-05-12","2021-05-15","2021-05-22"),user_ID=c("IZ823","TDH65","SI826"))
colnames(df2) <- c("Date", "user_ID")
```

The only way I found so far was to create some kind of flag ***Folder_True*** where it's a 1 if we know this user used **Folder** feature on this date and 0 if we don't know. I then used it with dplyr combining `group_by` and `sum`. But I think it's not very elegant and I would like to learn a more logical/efficient way to do this data wrangling.
Thanks!

```
df1 <- data.frame(Date=c("2021-05-12","2021-05-15","2021-05-20"),user_ID=c("RZ625","TDH65","EJ7336"), Folder_True=c(0,0,0))

df2 <- data.frame(Date=c("2021-05-12","2021-05-15","2021-05-22"),user_ID=c("IZ823","TDH65","SI826"), Folder_True=c(1,0,1))

combined_df <- rbind(df1, df2)

combined_df <-
  combined_df %>% 
  group_by(Date, user_ID) %>% 
  summarise(Folder_True = sum(Folder_True))

final_df <-
  combined_df %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarise(Nb_Users_Folder_True = sum(Folder_True))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `Date` you can find out unique users who have `Folder_True = 1`.

```
library(dplyr)

combined_df <- rbind(df1, df2)

combined_df %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarise(Nb_Users_Folder_True = n_distinct(user_ID[Folder_True == 1]))

#   Date       Nb_Users_Folder_True
#  <chr>                     <int>
#1 2021-05-12                    1
#2 2021-05-15                    0
#3 2021-05-20                    0
#4 2021-05-22                    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `uniqueN` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2))[,
        .(Nb_Users_Folder_True = uniqueN(user_ID[as.logical(Folder_True)])), Date]
```

-output

```
#           Date Nb_Users_Folder_True
#1: 2021-05-12                    1
#2: 2021-05-15                    0
#3: 2021-05-20                    0
#4: 2021-05-22                    1
```